# Calculate the number of working days between two dates by exiling the weekends and specific holidays with python

Tags: python

I have a holidays' list stored in an excel file. I would like to calculate the number of working days between two dates (`date_1` and `date_2`) by ignoring the holidays stored in my excel file.

I tried `np.busday_count` but I do not know how to include my holiday file. This is my code:

```
claim=pd.read_excel("claim.xlsx")
Holydays=pd.read_excel("Holidays.xlsx")
claim.columns

claim["Resolved"] = pd.to_datetime(claim["Resolved"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
claim["Received_date"] = pd.to_datetime(claim["Received_date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#Je définie mes dates
date_1=claim["Received_date"]
date_2=claim["Resolved"]

#Calcul du nombre de jours entre la date et la date de résolution du dossier
claim["nb_jours"] = np.busday_count(date_1, date_2)
```

Comment: You should try to provide some sample data for each dataframe. However it looks like you are only missing to subtract the number of holidays between date_1 and date_2. This can be done by Holydays[column_name].between(date_1, date_2).count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

maskcal=np.busdaycalendar(
    holidays=[
         '2019-12-24', 
         '2020-01-01', 
         '2020-01-06', 
         '2020-01-10'
                     ])

diff_days=np.busday_count(
      '2019-12-20', '2020-01-20', 
         busdaycal=maskcal
)
```

Output:

```py
17
```

The `np.busdaycalendar` is comprehensive to weekends (i.e. Saturday-Sunday). You just need to read your excel file, and format it into `list` of dates of `datetime`-readable format.

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz Skibinski. I try to put my holydays as list but I see this:

```
maskcal=np.busdaycalendar(holidays=Holydays['Date'].tolist())
[Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-02-20 00:00:00'),

 
```
And when I try to run your code, I get this error:

```

  File "<ipython-input-43-6c909260b6e1>", line 1, in <module>
    maskcal=np.busdaycalendar(holidays=Holydays['Date'].tolist())

ValueError: Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates
```

Comment: Try: ```Holydays['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.date()).tolist()```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. But it still does not work when I execute:
```maskcal=np.busdaycalendar(Holydays['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.date()).tolist())```
I get this error:
```ValueError: A business day weekmask array must have length 7```

Comment: You need to do: ```maskcal=np.busdaycalendar(holidays=Holydays['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.date()).tolist())```

Comment: For reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busdaycalendar.html you can specify weekdays (like '1111100' for mon-fri), and holidays on top of that.